# Having trouble calling a static method in main method

Tags: java

I've written a static method that method takes a single int parameter that is the numeric month and returns the number of days in the given month. So, a parameter of 1 would return 31 since there are 31 days in January and a parameter of 2 would return 28 since there are 28 days in February, so on and so forth.

However, when I try to call the static method in my main method, I get an error message that reads `void type not allowed here.` Can someone help me figure out what I've done wrong? Here is what I have so far:

```
public class Days {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

      System.out.println(daysInMonth(1));

   }
   public static void daysInMonth(int month) {
           if (month==1||month==3||month==5||month==7||month==8||month==10||month==12)
         System.out.println("31");
      else if (month==4||month==6||month==9||month==11)
         System.out.println("30");
      else if (month==2)
         System.out.println("28");
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know the difference between a `return` value and a method invocation that prints something to standard output?

Comment: You have two options. Either just call `daysInMonth(1)` without the surrounding `println` call or have `daysInMonth(...)` return `String`

Comment: As @SotiriosDelimanolis points out, in the `main` method, you call `println` on the return value of the `daysInMonth` method, but that method doesn't return a value. That method does all the printing, so your `main` method doesn't need to print. Or your `daysInMonth` method should return an `int` with the number of days, and keep the `println` in the `main` method.

Comment: I get it now, thank you!

Comment: Please note that not every February has 28 days; see also [leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year).

Answer (score 4):

Your method is `void`. You can't `print` a `void` value. You could change

```
System.out.println(daysInMonth(1));
```

to

```
daysInMonth(1);
```

**or** change `daysInMonth` to return the `int` value like

```
public static int daysInMonth(int month) {
    if (month == 1 || month == 3 || month == 5 || month == 7 || month == 8
            || month == 10 || month == 12)
        return 31;
    else if (month == 4 || month == 6 || month == 9 || month == 11)
        return 30;
    return 28;
}
```